# Is there a way to change Views base table dynamically?

Tags: views, 8, search

I have a couple of Search API indexes for different server environments (test, qa, uat, prod) with different configurations.

Instead of create 4 views in the admin, I just want to use one, and depending on environment, swap the base table (index). That way I can have one view at one URL.

Is that possible in Drupal 8?

Comment: Why do you have different indexes on the same site? Usually your whole site is test/staging/prod or however you call it and you have an index with the same name on each? Alternatively, you could have different servers, then you have a single index and can switch the server it is using

Comment: Using what? How do you do that?

Comment: Simpler is to build these 4 views, then create a controller extends ControllerBase on the path you want, in the contoller embed the view by env or by your param, I guess there is an exposed form to search so redirect on submit to the controller path passing the form values as query params, the embedded views automatically get the query params

Answer (score 0):

Just use configs overrides services like described here https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-override-system

Example:

```
if (in_array('views.view.config.name', $names)) {
  $overrides['views.view.config.name'] = ['base_table' => 'your_base_table'];
}
```